# Enable Massive Concurrent SSH to a single server

Tags: ssh, sshd, ulimit

My goal is to allow 10000 concurrent *ssh*s running on a *single* server.

For simplicity I am ssh-ing to localhost:

```
for i in `seq 1 10000`; do
    ssh localhost "echo ${i}; sleep 100"  >>./info 2>>./log &
done
```

`sleep 100` is to make sure when the 10000th ssh starts, the 1st ssh is still in connection so there are indeed 10000 *concurrent* *ssh*s.

And here are the two kinds of error messages I got:

```
1. ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

2. ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I have done the following modifications:

1. In `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`, set soft&hard `nofile`&`nproc` to 65535 (this is the max possible value right? -- Update: no. The max value is [1048576](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213069/5187710))
2. In `/etc/sysctl.conf`, set `kernel.pty.max = 65535`
3. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set `MaxStartups 10000`.

These modifications allow me to successfully run 1000 concurrent *ssh*s to a single server, but they don't work for 2000 and above *ssh*s.

Some people have suggested changing the value for `MaxSessions`(actually I'm not clear about its usage: how does multiplexing affect my case?), `/proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog` and `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`, but they seem to make no difference.

Besides, there's no error if they are 10000 concurrent *ssh*s to *different* servers (problems occur only when ssh to a *single* server):

```
for i in `seq 1 10000`; do
    j=$(( 1 + $i % 8 ))
    ssh server-${j} "echo hi; sleep 100" >info-${j} 2>log-${j} &
done
```

I've been stuck on this for quite long.
Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: sshd server log can provide more information about the reason for rejecting connections. Basically if you want just 10000 sessions, I would recommend you to use multiplexing using ControlMaster (and then of course bump MaxSessions).

Comment: I don't think the `sleep 100s` does what you think. It gets executed not in the ssh session, but on your own machine.

Comment: @Jakuje thanks for reminding me to check the server log! I found `error: reexec socketpair: Too many open files`, so I suppose the previous value of `nofile` (i.e. 65535) was far from enough. I am not familiar with ControlMaster but I'll try it, thank you!! :)

Comment: @danielkullmann sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. I use `sleep 100` because I want the first ssh to remain connected at the time the last ssh is established. When I tried 1000 *ssh*s (1000 was fine), `ps aux | grep ssh | grep -v sshd | wc -l` gave me the correct result 1001 (1000 for ssh + 1 for grep), so I think `sleep 100` achieves what I want, am I correct?

Comment: Interesting, when I do execute one of the lines, a `ps axu | egrep "ssh|sleep" | grep -v grep` only lists the `sleep 100s`, not the `ssh`. I think you should change the command to `ssh "echo hi; sleep 100s"`.

Comment: @danielkullmann Yes you are absolutely right -- `sleep 100` should be in the command sent through ssh, which is the case in my actual script, but I made a typo here. I have updated the main post accordingly. Thank you so much for pointing it out!!

Comment: Take a look at [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), it's an old article but still useful to know possible limitations and tweaks when you try to achieve extremely high concurrency and throughput on a single server.

Comment: It seems normal to everyone that the OP wants to open 10,000 concurrent SSH connections to a server? I can't think of a single legitimate reason that anyone would ever want to do this, although obviously it would be useful for malicious purposes... whats next? "Hi guys, I am trying to figure out how to deplete all server resources as quickly as possible, please help with my code..."

Comment: @Baazigar your worry is understandable but my question is for big data parallel processing. There's no crooked things happening :)

Answer (score 3):

/me wished he could comment

sshd needs to (typically, but though you didn't specifiy the exact use case(s) etc.) allocate a pty per login, however, in your case, ssh "echo hi; sleep 100s" does NOT allocate a pty, so no need for the kernel.pty.max setting... unless you want thousands of users *logged*in*... to test that, you'll need to add the -t option to your tests, ie. ssh -t "echo hi; sleep 100s"

Back to the issue at hand with the `error: reexec socketpair: Too many open files`
Tests on a Wheezy dist-upgraded to Jessie system, I found that /etc/security/limit* doesn't change the sshd's limits.

check that with `cat /proc/<pid-of-sshd>/limits`
which in my case, after setting in /etc/security/limits.conf:
   * nofile soft 65535
   * nofile hard 65535
still reports only 1024 (soft) and 4096(hard) for sshd's limits.
The resolution appears to be to force the `ulimit -Hn 65535` & `ulimit -n 65535` inside the `/etc/init.d/ssh` script
using that ulimit commands, I've raised the sshd's nofiles to 65535/65535 from 1024/4096

Answer (score 0):

The reason why /etc/security/limits.conf etc. has no effect is that it only applies for the users logged in via PAM (which does not include system services).

In order to set limits for services you could (example for Ubuntu 20) edit
/etc/systemd/system.conf and add a line such as:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=<Soft Limit>:<Hard Limit>
```

Seems like restarting sshd daemon alone is not enough - only after a system reboot (or possibly running "sudo systemctl daemon-reload") will the new settings take effect.

More details here:
https://medium.com/@shihtiy.tw/linux-max-open-file-limit-with-system-service-ca8ff2562d1c